# How to convert array to string in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I do to dislay players list without array?

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

$Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( 'localhost', 25565 );
    $players=print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ));

}
catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage( );
}
```

?>

Comment: `print_r` is only for debugging purposes.   It prints to the screen, and has no return value.  If you pass `true` as the second value, then it'll return a string and not print anything.  I think you want something like `implode(',', $Query->GetPlayers())`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create a list separated by the character(s) of your choosing:

```
// comma spearated
echo implode(',', $players);  
// John,Brian,Matthew

// <br> after each one but the last
echo implode('<br>', $players);
// John<br>Brian<br>Matthew
```

Comment: it doesn't works

Result
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\WebServ\httpd\mq\show.php on line 13

Comment: Then `$players` is not an array

Comment: I know ,it is a function, but it returns value what I want to implode

Comment: `$players` is **not** a function. It is a data type of some sort. Maybe an object. Maybe a string. Maybe something else. But it is not an array or function.

Comment: public function GetPlayers( )
 {
  return isset( $this->Players ) ? $this->Players : false;
 }

Comment: What can I do to get that result on the website: Player1, Player2?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know what data type `$players` is. Do `var_dump($players)` and post the output in your question.

Comment: where I should put it?

Comment: After `$players=print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ));`

Comment: It returns bool(true)

Comment: That means you don't have a list of players. You have something that returns true or false. You need to review the code to find out how to get an array of layers names as that code won't do it. Once you do that my code will work for you.

Comment: Wait, I forgot something

Comment: I don't enter the server
Now it returns Array ( [0] => Player1 ) bool(true)

Comment: My code should work for the array although there is only one player listed so you won't actually see anything happen.

Comment: May I send you all the code of MineQuery.class

=== Code ===
http://wklej.to/WfKnQ